# Change case of n-th letter in a string

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, sed, string

I want to change the case of the n-th letter of a string in `BASH` (or any other *nix tools, e.g. `sed`, `awk`, `tr`, etc).

I know that you can change the case a whole string using:

```
${str,,} # to lowercase
${str^^} # to uppercase
```

Is it possible to change the case of the 3rd letter of "Test" to uppercase?

```
$ export str="Test"
$ echo ${str^^:3}
TeSt
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bash you could do:

```
$ str="abcdefgh"
$ foo=${str:2}  # from the 3rd letter to the end
echo ${str:0:2}${foo^} # take the first three letters from str and capitalize the first letter in foo.
abCdefgh
```

In Perl:

```
$ perl -ple 's/(?<=..)(.)/uc($1)/e; ' <<<$str
abCdefgh
```

Or

```
$ perl -ple 's/(..)(.)/$1.uc($2)/e; ' <<<$str
abCdefgh
```

Comment: What is purpose of `~` in `perl` solution?

Comment: @cuonglm a typo. It was left over from a previous versin I tried where I was using `$ARGV[0]=~` instead of `<<<$str`. Thanks.

Comment: The `bash` can be shortened with `foo=${str:2}` and `${foo^}`, which only capitalizes the first character in the string.

Answer (score 7):

With GNU `sed` (possibly others)

```
sed 's/./\U&/3' <<< "$str"
```

With `awk`

```
awk -vFS= -vOFS= '{$3=toupper($3)}1' <<< "$str"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `perl`:

```
$ str="abcdefgh"
$ perl -pe 'substr($_,2,1) ^= " "' <<<"$str"
abCdefgh
```

- The general form is `substr($_,n,1)` where `n` is the position of letter you want to invert the case (0-based index).
- When you xor an ASCII character with space, you invert its case.

Comment: That's really cool, I didn't know that xor-ing an ascii character with space inverts its case.